# Does .NET 5 or 6 support Sqlite with database-first approach and .EDMX?

Tags: .net, sqlite, .net-5, edmx

How can we migrate a .NET 4.5.2 class library with `System.Data.SQlite`, database-first approach and an `.EDMX` model file to .NET 5 or .NET 6?

Comment: It's easy, you can't. EF6 died with .NET Framework. Copy the generated classes over to a new project and change references to EF Core

Comment: .NET 5 / 6 and EF Core 5 / 6 do no longer support the `.edmx` data model file. You will need to change this - either create your C# classes and generate the database from those ("code-first"), or else create your SQLite database using a separate tool, and then do a reverse-engineering (e.g. with the EF Core Power Tools) to get your classes and a suitable DbContext generated from the existing database

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others.

You will need to use scaffolding to generate context and classes associated like below :
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx